# Prove $f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$, with $\operatorname{Re}z=0$, is a unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

Here's what I did to graph

$$f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$$

where $\operatorname{Re}z=0$. Given $\operatorname{Re}z=0$, $z$ can be written as $z = iy$ and the function becomes

$$f(y) = \frac{iy-1}{iy+1}$$

If we separate into real and imaginary parts we get $$f(y) = \frac{y^2-1}{y^2+1}+\frac{2iy}{y^2+1} = \frac{(y+i)^2}{y^2+1},$$ even though the last equality didn't give anything to me. 
From that we get two functions: the real part $u(y) = \frac{y^2-1}{y^2+1}$ and the imaginary part $v(y) = \frac{2y}{y^2+1}$.

What I did next is to plot the points in the Argand plane. It appears to be a circle of radius 1, with the center at the origin. I guess its equation is something like $(\operatorname{Re}z)^2 + (\operatorname{Im}z)^2 = 1$, but excluding the point (1,0). However, I don't know how to obtain it analytically.

The question is: how can I prove that $f(y) = \frac{iy-1}{iy+1}$represents a circle of radius 1 and centered at origin. Is there a general method for the proof? Plotting the function with simple points is helpful, but not a proof.

Comment: To prove... **what** ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Prove that (if I'm right), the plot of that complex function is $($Re $z)^2$ + $($Im $z)^2 = 1$

Comment: Please do write **clearly** what the question *exactly* is in your post .

Comment: @DonAntonio Edited. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: No, it really is not...and I really have no idea what the answer below answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually straightforward to show that

$$w=\frac{iy-1}{iy +1}$$

represents a circle. Evaluate

$$|w|^2=w\bar{w}=\frac{iy-1}{iy +1}\cdot \frac{-iy-1}{-iy +1}
=1$$

which leads to the solution $w=e^{i \theta}$. Thus, $w$ describes  a unit circle with center at the origin. The exclusion of the point $w=1$ is seen from

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow \pm \infty} w
= \lim_{y\rightarrow \pm \infty} \frac{iy-1}{iy +1} =1$$

Edit:

Let $w=u+iv$. Then $|w|^2 = 1$ leads to

$$w\bar{w}=(u+iv)(u-iv)=1$$

or, in the form of equation for the real part,

$$u^2+v^2=1$$

which represents a unit circle with the center at the origin.

Comment: Your answer is definitely mathematically-correct but at my level, the equality $w=e^{i \theta}$ is too complicated. If you'd be so kind, can you please reformulate this in a less complicated way?

Comment: @GuyFawkes - Sure. I added the reformulation with $w=u+iv$ instead in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. That's much more clear now. And, probably, the last question. How do we come to $|w|^2$? How do we understand that we need to evaluate exactly that?

Comment: @GuyFawkes - Observe that $w$ is supposed to represent a unit circle. Therefore, its magnitude is expected to be $|w|=1$.

Comment: Thank you. That seems clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach is right. Apply the assumptions to the function, then find real and imaginary parts and interpret that as a plot in the complex plane. Proving what shape it is depends on the problem.

Regarding your example,

$$f(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$$
If the real part is always zero then
$$f(z)=\frac{-1+iy}{1+iy}\frac{1-iy}{1-iy}=\frac{-1+2iy+y^2}{1+y^2}=\frac{y^2-1}{y^2+1}+i\frac{2y}{1+y^2}.$$
So you have
$$u(t)=\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}\quad\text{and}\quad v(t)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$
I plotted this with Mathematica,

```
ParametricPlot[{(t^2 - 1)/(t^2 + 1), 2 t/(1 + t^2)}, {t, -11, 6}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

so it looks like you get a circle since $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

These are the [tangent half-angle substitution formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#Euler_and_Weierstrass) a.k.a Euler/Weierstrass substitution formulae. According to [this article about the geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#Geometry) of these equations, the point $(-1,0)$ is never reached, which corresponds to the point $(1, 0)$ given our equations (it's negated). Also you can make the substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$ and work through the algebra you will find $u(t)=-\cos x$ ad $v(t)=\sin x$, but I guess there must be some restrictions on $x$ since the point $(1,0)$ is never reached.

[image]

Comment: I haven't applied the formula you provided yet, but I'm almost sure, that point (1;0) doesn't belong to the plot, as $\lim_{t\to \infty} u(t) = 1$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty} v(t) = 0$.

Comment: @GuyFawkes I think you are right - check out this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#Geometry PS using the substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$ is most likely how you would prove it's a unit circle, centre zero, and there will probably be some restrictions on the $x$ value to avoid the point $(1,0)$.